# Images located on a separate server -- is there overhead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm planning to upload images to facebook to my account first, get their "src" and then show them in my Rails app where `img src` will point to the location of the images at facebook that I've uploaded them.

Is there overhead in this approach as opposed having images in my own website? Will that slow down the server? And will this approach do in general? Is it legal?

Comment: If you're not worried about spamming your fb account with random images, shouldn't be a problem legally. Overhead -> Technically no overhead would happen if you're planning to use them directly in img tags

Comment: Facebook will probably stop you

Comment: Because Facebook is not a CDN for you.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no overhead, in fact this could actually speed up your app by reducing the load of request your server will receive. This is basically like using a distributed CDN for your javascript and css.

Typically your rails server will serve an html response with links to css, javascript, and images. The user's browser then starts rendering this html and will make requests when it encounters these links. If all these links point back to your server, then your rails server has to handle serving these static assets (and it can only handle so many requests per second).

In production its common to put your assets on a CDN such as Amazon Web Services to decrease the load on your rails server. As long as your facebook image is public, I believe this is actually a good idea.